# Java modular division

Tags: java, division, modular-arithmetic

I'm doing some error correcting, and I need to divide two digits under mod 11 in Java.

Now this I know, from using a modular calculator:

```
9/1 mod 11 = 9
2/10 mod 11 = 9
```

The problem comes in getting Java to calculate this.  In Java:

```
(9 / 1) % 11 = 9 - This is fine
(2 / 10) % 11 = 0 - This is not correct.
```

I know that Java cannot technically perform modular operations, and part of me is thinking that I either need to somehow calculate the inverse, or use an array to store the possible output values.

Comment: Err, 2 / 10 is 0. And 0 % 11 is 0. Why would it be 9?

Comment: Because I'm doing it under mod 11.  Not normal division.

Comment: What I've just done is: (2 * 10) % 11 = 9.  Which seems to be giving me my correct answer.

Comment: Ah, of course. But multiplication and division are not exactly the same thing. You found the correct problem for your solution.

Comment: So what is the question? You found out that you had to use multiplication instead of division... There is no question. I voted to close.

Comment: @stivlo: the question is about inverting multiplication in [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).  Because 10 is its own inverse mod 11, multiplying by 10 and dividing by 10 has the same effect in modulo-11 arithmetic.  That's why Tony happens to get the correct answer a few comments above.

Comment: @LukeWoodward thanks, I got it, then the way to go is define his own class, with its equality operator, it's division, multiplication and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is how to find the multiplicative inverse of a number modulo 11.

10 is its own inverse modulo 11, so it isn't a particularly useful example.  Instead, let's find the multiplicative inverse of 7 modulo 11.

To do this, we solve the equation 7a + 11b = 1 for a and b in integers.  We use the [Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) to find suitable values for a and b.  In this case, we can take a = -3 and b = 2.  We ignore the value of b, and take a ( = -3) to be the inverse of 7 modulo 11.  In modulo-11 arithmetic, 7 times -3 is 1.

If we don't like negative numbers, we can take the inverse of 7 modulo 11 to be 8 ( = -3 + 11) instead.

So, instead of dividing by 7 modulo 11, we multiply by -3, or by 8.  For example, in modulo-11 arithmetic, 9 / 7 = 9 * 8 = 72 = 6.

If you only ever have one modulus to work with (e.g. you only ever work modulo 11), it's probably better to calculate a table of multiplicative inverses modulo 11 beforehand and use that in your calculations.

Comment: Thanks for that Luke, I had a suspicion that's what I was going to have to do.  Do you have any advice on generating such a table?  I'm guessing I need a multi-dimensional array?

Comment: I don't see why you'd need a multidimensional array.  If you only ever work modulo 11, calculate of the inverses of 1 to 10 modulo 11 and put them in a 1-dimensional array.  If you're working with lots of moduli, or any large moduli, a table won't be such a good idea.

Comment: Thanks Luke, I was getting a bit confused with what I was trying to do (it's still quite early for me) :).  I've now built an inverse table using an array, and now everything is working as planned.  Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Luke, you've been a massive help, and I was wondering if I could ask of your help for a final time.  Simply, I need a way in Java of it outputting 7, when I put in y = -4 % 11.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @Tony: one possible expression that handles negative numbers as well as positive numbers is `((y % 11) + 11) % 11`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you intend, but...

```
public static int divmod(int dividend, int divisor, int mod) {
    if (dividend >= divisor)
        return (dividend / divisor) % mod;
    return mod - dividend;
}
```

Testing it:

```
divmod(9, 1, 11)  // returns 9
divmod(2, 10, 11) // returns 9
```

Comment: Thanks Óscar,  this works for some number pairs, but fails for others.

Comment: Give me a set of numbers for testing, specially the ones that fail, and I'll see what I can do to help you